# Convert Proxy Server to open internet connection

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, proxy-server

My college provides internet access via wifi and uses a proxy server. Every time when I open my browser I have to enter user name and password for internet access.

Is there any way to **convert proxy server internet access to open internet access** using VPN or any other service so that I can access internet in my system without using any proxy address and port ?

Comment: i am able to open any website ..but some applications i am unable to use.

Comment: Do you have the proxy setup within thunderbird? Please specify which Applications dont work.

Comment: thunderbird, i have set proxy it asks for username, password after entering the username and password it doesn't load mails. after sometime it shows timed out.

Comment: Have you configure the proxy settings within thunderbird, It has its own connection. It does not use the settings from Internet Explorer.

Comment: yes, i have set to it's own like firefox.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to "Convert proxy to open internet"

However, there are some work around methods.

For example.

Using Google Translator -

```
http://www.google.com/translate?langpair=en|en&u=**www.blockedsite.com**
```

Using Google Cached pages -

Google the site and click the down arrow and click `cached` option.

Comment: i didn't get. what it will do ? I am able to access internet by using proxy server.

Comment: Yes, what is your reason to bypass? Do you want to access a site that is restricted?

Comment: i am unable to update msse using proxy server, unable to use thunderbird etc

Comment: Ah ok, in this case. Please read. http://superuser.com/questions/453825/how-to-bypass-web-url-filtering-service-to-access-blocked-websites-proxy